# Why is my modulo condition in my prime number tester not working?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm trying (and failing) to write a simple function that checks whether a number is prime.  The problem I'm having is that when I get to an if statement, it seems to be doing the same thing regardless of the input. This is the code I have:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x % i != 0:    #if x / i remainder is anything other than 0
                print "1"
                break
            else:
                print "ok"
        else:
            print "2"
    else: print "3"

is_prime(13)
```

The line with the comment is where I'm sure the problem is. It prints "1" regardless of what integer I use as a parameter. I'm sorry for what is probably a stupid question, I'm not an experienced programmer at all.

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces in your post here. Make sure you don't in your actual file. Run the script with `python -tt` and correct any problems it reports. Preferably, configure your editor to use *only* spaces for indentation, following the PEP 8 styleguide recommendation.

Comment: whats the value of the variable i , on the if statement?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No I used only tabs in the actual code, I added the spaces to format the code correctly in my question. I tried running the script with `python -tt` and still only got a "1".

Comment: @scrineym The i is supposed to be incrementing by 1 in the for loop, have I done something wrong?

Comment: also there are three else statements in the code but only 2 if statements I'm not sure of the in's and outs of python but I'm not sure if that is possible ?

Comment: @Taint no you've done nothing wrong with the i variable, it was down to my bad eyesight, my apologies.

Comment: @scrineym The bottom else statement is for the first if statement, the middle else statement is to be executed at the end of the for loop if the loop isn't broken and the top else statement is for the 2nd if statement.

Comment: @Taint: I fear you failed to properly 'fix' the indentation. I have re-indented everything, please do check if things are still as you intended.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your formatting did fix the code, I don't know how I indented it wrong but it's working now, thank you. I'll be more wary of that from now on.

Comment: You have three 'else' statements, but only two 'if' statements. I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is actually really close to being functional. You just have a logical error in your conditional.

There are some optimizations you can make for a [primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) like only checking up until the square root of the given number.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x % i == 0: # <----- You need to be checking if it IS evenly
                print "not prime" # divisible and break if so since it means
                break             # the number cannot be prime
            else:
                print "ok"
        else:
            print "prime"
    else:
        print "not prime"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed the conditional but now it's telling me every number _is_ prime, so what is wrong here?

Edit: can't format the code properly, but all I did was change the conditional to `if x % i == 0:` and delete the else statement for the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
if x % i != 0:
```

You are testing if `x % i` is *not* 0, which is true for any pair of integers that are relatively prime (hence, you always get it printed out)

It should be:

```
if x % i == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using return statements instead of (or in addition to) print statements, eg:

```
from math import sqrt # for a smaller range

def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 2:
        return True
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(x)) + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            print "%d is divisible by %d" % (x,i)
            return False
    return True    

is_prime(13)
True

is_prime(14)
14 is divisible by 2
False
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of checks can be single expression:

```
def is_prime(n):
    return n>1 and all(n%k for k in range(2,n//2))
```